# About Routes in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Can I say that all controllers in Laravel 4 are RESTful controllers by default?
How to make a non RESTful controller?
what's the difference between RESTful controller and resource controller?

```
// routes.php
Route::get('/', 'HomeController');
```

Can I say that HomeController is a RESTful controller?

Comment: great question, because Jordan's answer, answers my questions. You should consider it as the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a RESTful controller, the method names are prefixed with the HTTP verb they should respond to, so a if you assign the TaskController to the URI tasks like so:

```
Route::controller('tasks', 'TaskController');
```

and do a GET request to `/tasks/info` that would call the `TaskController@getInfo` method. See http://four.laravel.com/docs/controllers#restful-controllers for more details.

In a resourceful controller, there are predefined methods available which match to automatic routes that are created. You can assign a resourceful controller to a route like so:

```
Route::resource('lists', 'ListController');
```

This then allows you to do a GET request to `/lists/1` for example which should show the list with an ID of 1 and calls the `ListController@show` method. A full list is available here: http://four.laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers.

To answer the first question, no all controllers are not RESTful by default unless you assign them using `Route::controller()`. A normal controller is used by assigning routes to controller methods manually like so:

```
Route::get('about', 'HomeController@about');
```

or for a named route:

```
Route::get('about', array(
'as' => 'about',
'uses' => 'HomeController@about'
));
```

Comment: No worries, you can accept this answer if you feel it answers your question.

Comment: great, that answers my question.

Comment: but I guess in a way the default registration of controllers by name is restful. @Jordan do you think it is best to use RESTful controllers in Laravel 3, is there a reason for a page to be requested by post when it shouldn't?

Comment: Sorry I haven't been on for a while! I honestly haven't worked that much with Laravel 3, but the idea is that using a RESTful controller means you don't have to create routes for HTTP verbs as this is handled automatically by prefixing the method with the verb. If you were adding multiple routes for http verbs you probably should be using a restful controller.